# calculate grand total with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I don't know how to get Grand total value

grand total is sum of all total

here is the code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'a.karat');
if(isset($_POST['product_id']))
{
$prno=$_POST['prno'];
$i=1;
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from detail_pr where prNo='$prno'");
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

    echo 

    '<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="check'.$i.'"    value="'.$i.'"></td>
 <td><label for="productCode"></label>
  <input type="text" name="productCode'.$i.'" id="productCode'.$i.'" readonly value="'.$r["productCode"].'" size="12" ></td>
<td><label for="productName"></label>
  <input type="text" name="productName'.$i.'" id="productName'.$i.'" readonly value="'.$r["productName"].'"size="35" ></td>
<td><label for="qty"></label>
  <input type="number" onkeyup="calc(this);" name="qty'.$i.'" id="qty'.$i.'" readonly value="'.$r["qty"].'" size="8" ></td>
<td><input type="number" onkeyup="calc(this);" name="price'.$i.'" id="price'.$i.'" size="10" min="1" max="99" onchange="calc(this);" ></td>
<td><input type="number" onkeyup="calc(this);" name="discount'.$i.'" id="discount'.$i.'" size="10" min="0" max="99" onchange="calc(this);"></td>
<td><input type="number" name="total'.$i.'" id="total'.$i.'" size="10" min="1" max="99" onchange="calc(this);" ></td>
  </tr>';
  $i++;
    }
}
?>


<table width="400" border="0" align="right">
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">Grand Total</th>
     <td>:</td>
    <td><input name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
     function calc(id) {
  var row = id.parentNode.parentNode;
  var quant = row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var price = row.cells[4].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var disc = row.cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  if (disc == null || disc == '') {
    res = parseFloat(quant) * parseFloat(price);
  } else {
    var res = (parseFloat(quant) * parseFloat(price)) - (parseFloat(quant) *     parseFloat(price) * (parseFloat(disc) / 100));
  }
  row.cells[6].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = res;
}
</script>
```

I have manage to calculate total per row

now I need your help to sum all total and put the value in the grandtotal textbox

Comment: what are the variable names that you want to sum and see in grand total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess on every change of a value of one of your input elements in your form the grand total should be updated, right? I 'd place an event listener on the form tag to keep it simple.

```
<form id="your-form" method="post" action="">
    <!-- All your other inputs here -->
    <input type="text" name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal">
</form>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#your-form').addEventListener('change', function( event ) {
        if (event.target.id && event.target.id !== 'grandtotal') {
            var allTotals = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="total"]'),
                allTotalSum = 0;

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(allTotals, function( element ) {
                if (element.value) {
                    allTotalSum += parseFloat(element.value);
                }
            });

            document.querySelector('#grandtotal').value = allTotalSum;
        }
    });
</script>
```

So on every change of one of your input fields the sum is updated. This code is untested.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Marcel, yes on every change of one of my input fields the sum is updated. the result of your code is NaN

Comment: It depends of what type of value your inputs with the name beginning with "total.." have. I guess it is a float, right? Instead of parseInt() give parseFloat() a try. If this is not working debug your values with console.log(element.value);

Comment: your code works perfectly if  I input all the data, ex = when I retrieve 2 data (2 rows) from database than I input the first row, the result is Nan but when I input all of them (2 rows), the grand total show the result,

Comment: You can check, if a value is given like `if (element.value) { allTotalSum += parseFloat(element.value);  }`.

Comment: perfect, your code works perfectly, thank a lot @Marcel